# How to compare parameter pattern to URL parameters by native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, client-side

How to compare parameter pattern to URL parameters by native JavaScript?

For example my cache value is `__/v1/abc/abcd/?lat=40.12323&lon=2.1342&radius=1&x=gdfgdf`

I'd like to compare this regex pattern `lat=[*]&lon=[*]&radius=[*]` to above cache value:

Does my cache include this challenge?

```
if (cache.regex(abovepattern)) {


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cache="__/v1/abc/abcd/?lat=40.12323&lon=2.1342&radius=1&x=gdfgdf";


if(cache.match(/lat=([-+]?\d+\.\d+)&lon=([-+]?\d+\.\d+)/))
{
      // Your Code Match
}
else
{
      // Your Code On Not Match
}
```